# Optim function does not give right solution

Tags: r, coefficients, optim

I'm trying to optimize coefficients using the optim function in R. This is the function I'm trying to minimize :

```
min.RSS = function(data, par){
  sum(
    ((data$CCI) - 
      10^(par[1]+par[2]*data$Landsat +
         par[3]*data$Landsat^2 +
         par[4]*data$Landsat^3 + 
         par[5]*data$Landsat^4))^2, na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

I tried all the method in optim and none gives a right result.
[Example of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1ls7.png)
This is I think due to my data. My dataset contain more than 1.600.000 values and most of them are close to 0. I tried to by-pass this issue when restraining my dataset in order to have more homogenous value with this function :

```
df_nouveau <- data[data$CCI >= 2 | runif(nrow(data)) < 0.01, ]
```

I got better results with this function but still not what I expected.
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKeSZ.png)
The real interest of this optimization is to catch the dynamic (big augmentation or diminution in the values) and not to predict precisely the low concentration.
Do anyone know how to do this ?

Comment: I see two possible issues, 1) you are raising 10 to the power of something (and then squaring it also) which could be very large, 2) you are summing everything. Both of these things could result in huge unstable numbers.

Comment: The function estimating the data$CCI value is actually the one I write here (equation already used by the NASA etc to compute what I do here) so I can not really change it. What would you recommend me to put as function to minimise?

Comment: Please link a reference to `min.RSS`.

Comment: What do you meann by link a reference ? Like where do this equation comes from ? https://oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov/resources/atbd/chlor_a/ This is the second equation on this website.

Comment: Why are you using `optim` and not `nls`? Are you sure that you can't take the `log10` of the LHS and RHS and simply use `lm`? (The answer to the latter question depends on assumption regarding the error structure.)

Comment: What is the difference between optim and nls ? I can take log(CCI) - (a0 + a1*log(Landsat) etc

Answer (score 1):

The main part of the exponent, i.e.

```
     par[1]+par[2]*data$Landsat +
     par[3]*data$Landsat^2 +
     par[4]*data$Landsat^3 + 
     par[5]*data$Landsat^4
```

is a polynomial in `data$Landsat`.  There are other parametrizations of polynomials besides the sum of powers, and they are often more numerically stable.

For example, I'd try using orthogonal polynomials instead, which is the default used by the `poly()` function in R.  To do this, you pre-calculate the matrix

```
M <- cbind(1, poly(data$Landsat, 4))
```

then `min.RSS` could be

```
min.RSS = function(data, par){
  sum(
    ((data$CCI) - 10^(M %*% par))^2, na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

The solution `par` will not give the same coefficients as yours, but the possible predictions of this formulation match yours exactly.  There is a transformation of `par` to obtain yours if you really care about the individual coefficients--but that is usually not a useful calculation to do.  The predictions of the model are what matter.

Comment: How can I do the same thing with this equation : log(CCI) = a0 + a1*log(Landsat) + a2*log(landsat)^2 +a3*log(landsat)^3+a4*log(landsat)^4 ?

Comment: That's a linear model, which is much easier.  Just use `lm(log(CCI) ~ poly(log(Landsat), 4), data = ...)`.